# How to allocate an Int32 number for a GUID string?

Tags: java

We want to allocate a Int32 value for a coming new GUID, which is not exist in our system. 
One solution is to use auto-incremental Id in Mysql, but it's not convenient for later usages. Another method is to use a Hash function, to hash the GUID string to a Int32, but 32bit is too short to avoid high hash collision.
Any other solution for this issue?

Comment: Just curious, what's wrong with using the actual GUID instead?

Comment: We want to mapping guid to Int32 to make some bit operations by bitmap index.

Comment: "but it's not convenient for later usages" - how exactly do you find it inconvenient?

Comment: As I said above, we want to use bitmap index, so we should change each GUID to a Int32 and map each Int32 to one position in Bitmap cardinality.

Comment: Using an Int32 where you should use a GUID is going to run you into trouble sooner or later. And if you think about a bitmap index, if you think at that low level, the trouble will come sooner.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to not use the GUID? What operations do you want to perform with this Int32? Are you certain none of those operations require the int to be globally unique?

Comment: Where is the problem with having a table containing the mapping between the GUID and an auto-increment integer?

Comment: The reason of Int32 limitation is because of some bitmap compressed object(FastBit, EWAH, RoaringBitmap) only support the length of Int32. And the total count of GUIDs are less than Int32.Max().

Comment: @CodesInChaos for each new GUID come into system, we should find it in mysql to identify if it is exist. It is too complicated structure to solve high traffic, single-point problem, and performance.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that if you require high index performance on GUIDs and your database can't index them, you're using the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: You're presenting us with an "X-Y" problem: you want to solve X, have come up with a possible solution Y, and want to know how to implement Y. If you simply describe X, then you'll get far better answers.

Comment: However, if you're intent on implementing Y, at least explain what you're using the bitmap index for, because as-written it doesn't make a lot of sense. And based on the things that a bitmap index would do for you, it's likely that a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) would be a better solution. Or alternatively, some after-the-fact clustering algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't fit a GUID into a 32 bit number, your only recourse is a lookup table.

I suggest that you create said lookup table in your database, having two columns: one for the GUID, and one with an auto-incrementing `int32`, set as the Primary Key.  When you want a new GUID to `int32` conversion, simply INSERT a new record into the table, assigning your candidate GUID to the GUID column.

It's probably a good idea to never delete any records from this table as a matter of policy, as you don't ever want the `int32` assignment for a particular GUID to change.  Make sure you index the GUID column, **no duplicates.**

Note that you can co-opt an existing table for this purpose, if it makes sense to do so (i.e. the table that already uses the GUID as a Primary Key).  Just add your auto-incrementing field there.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the mysql solution. For all new GUID, each operation need nearly 0.6s, it is too slow for the high traffic system. For some exist GUIDs, the speed is better.

Comment: Something is wrong.  How many records are in that table?  Do you have the proper indexes?  Are you counting the time required to make a connection to the database?

Comment: sorry, it's 0.6ms,I got the wrong unit.

Comment: Six-tenths of a millisecond is not a long time for a database operation.  How many of these guid/int pairs do you need, and how fast?

Comment: 0.6ms is fast, because I keep one mysql connection to do all the operations. If it is in the high traffic distributed environment, the GUID will come hugely, 10,000~100,000 GUIDs per second should be operated. I think it's not easy to keep them use the same one connection to do it.

Comment: For me, a hash solution is better because it is not necessary to query database. Actually, for the coming lots of GUIDs, I do not need the continuous number to order it, the skip number is also OK, only to keep no same one number for two different GUIDs.

Comment: At 100,000 per second, you'll run out of unique int32 numbers in six hours.

Comment: The input streaming both have new and old GUIDs.

Comment: How many unique guids will be in play at any given time?

Comment: More then 10,000 per second. Actually, we collect the online user's action  logs, which includes pc and mobile's deviceid(like GUID), the data is coming into system continuously. I want to make each device a integer ID to  do some bitmap indexing.

Comment: At 10,000 per second, you'll run out of unique int32 numbers is 60 hours.  Is that a long enough time interval?

Comment: The total number of GUID is lower then Int32.Max. That's definitely.